# canceling gparted ( resize ) and a the data disappeared

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ntfs, gparted

i have a 1 TB HDD , it was 2 partitions .. the first one was empty and the second one contains 200 GB of data . i tried to resize and extend the second partition to be all the HDD . using the GPARTED as root .. the notifications showed around 4 hours ... i canceled it after about 15 minutes .. but i found the whole HDD is unknown file system

i tried to solve the issue by formatting the hard to NTFS and try to recover the data by a program i use on my old windows laptop ... but the result was disappointing ...

i didn't write any thing on the HDD till now and i need advise so i can recover that data ... it's very variable and it contains all my 10 years work

so please help me

Comment: Take a look at [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Answer (score 0):

If you data was initially in a ntfs partition you may still be able to use [GetDataBack](http://www.runtime.org/gdb.htm) to recover some of your data. The company u work for has used that to recover data from hard rives with a partition corruption/overwrite.

If you did a full format (the long one) however, your data is most likely gone.